# How can I merge two Account custom objects into one without saving it to the database?

Tags: apex, dml, merge

I have two saved account objects with the same Name and Email.
Use case:

1. I need to display these two objects' data to a user.
2. The user selects one master object
3. System merges whole non-master object into master object, but it doesn't updates it;
4. The user reviews the Merged object and presses a 'Save' button.

The principle of merging:

Account1(master): Name: AAAA; Email: BBB; Address: 111; State:

Account2: Name: AAAA; Email: BBB; Address: CCC; State: DDD

Result: Name: AAAA; Email: BBB; Address: 111; State: DDD

There is the 'merge' DML operation, but it saves a result object. Are there any OOB solutions?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. This is possibly an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] your question to explain what it is precisely you're trying to do, and why, so we can better assist you.

Comment: Are you referring to the standard Account object (with a custom e-mail field) or a custom object? (The title is a bit ambiguous.)